# How can I print the entire email message without Google chopping off some of the text?

Tags: gmail, printing

How can I print the entire email message without Google chopping off some of the text?  Usually less than all of the text is available for printing.

Answer (score 5):

To print an email (or an entire conversation), you have to use Gmail buttons.

On the top right corner of the mail, there is this icon: [image: print mail]
Click on the down arrow, then you will get a menu, just choose `Print`.

If you want to print the entire conversation, click on the printer icon [image: printer icon] on the top right of the conversation (at the right edge of the title/label line).

You can find official documentation [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8255?hl=en).

If this is how you proceed, I can't help you, I haven't seen Gmail chopping my printed emails, even in case of (very) long emails.

Comment: This answer no longer answers the question as it is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Click on the Icon for 'New Window' (upper right corner).  This reduces the space wasted on GMail headers.
2. In that new window, click on the "Print All" Icon (upper right corner).  This pops up a Preview with Print controls.
3. It may now say 'n sheets of paper' for an n-page email. If so you can print now.
4. If not, pulldown 'Pages' where it says 'All' and select 'Custom'.
5. Fill in the Custom range.  e.g 1-2.
6. Print.

Answer (score -1):

I  select Shrink to 50% and the whole message is printed but obvious a lot smaller but very readable,

Answer (score -3):

Click on print preview and select Shrink to fit under scale.  That solved the problem for me

Comment: This does not seem to be the problem. The asker is saying that Google is cutting the text, so that is not available to the printing software.